# Discord.py edit buttons style and text with on_interaction

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, discord-interactions

I introduced the new buttons on my discord robot and I still don't know them very well and I don't really understand them. I want to make a kind of switch buttons (turn on / off) in which to change both the color and the text. But I want to do this based on on_interaction because when I turn off the robot I don't have to re-enter the button creation command.

This is the code by which I create the buttons:

```
@commands.command(name="buttons")
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setup(self, ctx):
    button1 = Button(label='Turn on f1', custom_id='option1', emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    button2 = Button(label='Turn on f2', custom_id='option2', emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    button3 = Button(label='Turn on f3', custom_id='option3', emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    button4 = Button(label='Turn on f4', custom_id='option4', emoji="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)

    view = View()
    view.add_item(button1)
    view.add_item(button2)
    view.add_item(button3)
    view.add_item(button4)
    await ctx.send("Buttons", view=view)
```

And this is the code of on_interaction through which I can detect if the interaction is button and which is custom_id.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_interaction(self, interaction):
    data = interaction.data
    type = data['component_type']
    custom_id = data['custom_id']
    if type == 2:
        print("This is a button")
        if custom_id == "option1":
            print("button 1 selected")
        elif custom_id == "option2":
            print("button 2 selected")
    else:
        print("This isn't a button")
```

I don't understand / know how to select these buttons to edit. (I managed to do this in a function where the buttons of course come predefined) but I want this function to work even if the robot is restarted without setting the command again.

Comment: Are you looking for button style? [`ButtonStyle`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=buttonstyle#discord.ButtonStyle)

Comment: No, I want to edit the buttons on the on_interaction method. When you press the button, the button changes the style and text of the button. But through the on_interaction method so that it can always work.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```py
import discord
from discord import ui
from discord.ext import commands

onoffswitch = True

@bot.command()
async def onoff(ctx):
  global onffswitch
  em = discord.Embed(title="SWITCH")
  button = ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,label="Switch On", emoji="")
  # red="", green=""
  view = ui.View()
  view.add_item(button)
  button_edit = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, label="sus", emoji="☠")
  await ctx.send(embed=em, view=view)
  button.callback = on_interaction

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_interaction(interaction):
    view = View()
    global onoffswitch
    if onoffswitch:
      button_edit = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, label="Switch On", emoji="")
      em_followup = discord.Embed(title="Switched Off!", color=0xFF0000)
    else:
      button_edit = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, label="Switch Off", emoji="")
      em_followup = discord.Embed(title="Switched On!", color=0x00FF00)
    onoffswitch = not onoffswitch
    view.add_item(button_edit)
    em = discord.Embed(title="SWITCH")
    await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=em, view=view)
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=em_followup, ephemeral=True)
    button_edit.callback = on_interaction
```